# How do I get the the google chrome chrome.windows.create extension function to work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need some help with the chrome.windows.create function in javascript I just cant seem to work it out
Heres the html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function load() {
            chrome.windows.create({ url: 'http://www.google.com', type: 'panel' });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onLoad="load()">
</body>
```

Comment: Read the documentation, [CSP](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html). And make sure that the page is running in the extension's process (background/event/options/popup/... page)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inline javascript codes are not allowed (by default) in chrome extensions. so you have to change the code like this.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    <script src="loader.js"></script>
```

### loader.js:

```
function load() {
 chrome.windows.create({ url: 'http://www.google.com', type: 'panel' });
}
document.getElementsByTagName( 'body' )[0].onload = function() { load(); };
```

For more information about content-security policies visit: [Content Security Policy (CSP) - Google Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html)

Comment: I have another question you may be able to answer why does no extension I make even a copy of someone elses that does work not work

Comment: you have to add  "content_security_policy" field with suitable value in extension's manifest.json file. you can explore the manifest.json file of that extension ( which uses inline script ) and get the  suitable value from it.

Comment: How do I pick a suitable value for my extension

Comment: i didn't studied much about that. also i didn't used it, because we can select any element in a page easily using jquery. so i don't have to use inline js.

Comment: All works now thanks just used "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'"

Comment: Thank you dude, for getting back with right solution. i liked that :)